# Sum geometrically $\sum_{l=1}^{n} l^9 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do I solve the sum:

$$\sum_{l=1}^{n} l^9 $$

I was asked to solve this geometrically

Comment: We have $\sum_{k=1}^n k^9 = \frac{1}{20}(2n^{10}+10n^9+15n^8-14n^6+10n^4-3n^2)$, see [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html). For a geometrically proof, see there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: the geometric proof is for exponent... $1$.

Comment: Exactly, I need the geometric proof for the case where the exponent=9. I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is find the value of the geometric series $$G(x)=1+e^x+e^{2x}+\cdots+e^{nx}$$ using geometry. For example use the following type diagram with appropriate common ratio. Then compute $$G^{(9)}(0)=1^9+2^9+\cdots+n^9.$$

[image]

Comment: Why would we assume $(1 + e^x + e^{2x} + .... e^{nx})^9 = 1^9 + 2^9 + ..... + n^9$?

Comment: @fleablood I think he means the $9$th derivative of $G$ at $0$.

Comment: This is a clever answer, but computing the derivatives will be arduous, unless there's some trick I'm not seeing.

Comment: @saulspatz: I agree with you. One trick is to use [Faà di Bruno's formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) But still it is not an easy task.

Comment: I am following  this question but I don't understand how to derive the value of the geometric series G(x) using geometry.

Comment: @Sunitdas: For a finite geometric series, you wouldn't need the whole base line, but a truncation. But still you can compute the finite series using the same picture.

Comment: " @fleablood could you please explain the picture?"  Um.... what?  Why should I explain the picture.

Comment: Okays, so the $9$th derivative of $1 + e^x + ....... +e^{nx}$ at $0$ is $1+2^9 + .... + n^9$ but... how are we supposed to know what the value of the ninth derivative of $G(x)$ at $0$ is in the first place.  I mean... we can calculate what $G(k)$ is for any $k$ but that doesn't in anyway tell us what any derivatives are evaluate to.

Comment: @fleablood: I do not understand your objection. We compute a closed form for $G(x)$ and compute its ninth derivative (in two ways).

Comment: @fleablood $$G(x)=\frac{e^{10x}-e^x}{e^x-1}$$  Now you can calculate the successive derivatives of $G$, is you're dedicated enough.

Comment: "We compute a closed form for G(x) and compute its ninth derivative (in two ways)."  But calculating the $9$th derivative of $\frac {e^{(n+1)x} -1}{e^x -1}$ is surely not practical.

Comment: @fleablood: I agree. But if you think of the series $\sum k^9,$ any derivation of it (from first principals) certainly will not be short.